# Cannot install Boot Camp 3.1 drivers on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macbook, boot-camp

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 install (thru bootcamp) on my 17" Macbook Pro, with the bootcamp 3.0 drivers. Whenever I run the apple software update to install the 3.1 drivers, it downloads and installs them, then reboots, and when I've rebooted, it's still stuck on version 3.0 according to 'about boot camp' on the system tray icon. I've tried installing several times, it keeps happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end i solved this by downloading the 3.1 update from apple's site directly and running it, then providing the bootcamp64.msi when it prompts

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem! Make sure to mark your answer as accepted once enough time has passed to do so. Happy computing!